# PHP Login/Register security

Tags: php, security, authentication, registration

I start learning PHP and I would like to ask you what is the best way how to store users data. I have read a lot of articles about sessions and cookies.

I want to keep my web the most secured as I can and a lot of people say sessions is wrong way. What do you mean? Should I use cookies instead or is there another way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are seeking to store data for future use, you should be using persistent storage like database

Comment: Sessions are a bit of the laziest approach. They have less security impact themselves or trying to utilize your own cookies however. // Be sure to read up on proper password hashing instead.

Comment: Thanks everyone for response. Actually I want to know if I should use cookies or sessions to store user data because of security. For example, I have a login/register form connected with SQL database and want to show in a navigation user account name after login.

Answer (score 0):

To make your login more secure try to make the session name difficult to know use:
$_SESSION ['udoejeshsh12']  = $email
instead of 
$_SESSION['user'] = $email 
 to store your session because if anybody made a login page using your session name he/she can login into your login page

Comment: This key name has **no** impact on the session cookie (PHPSESSID= per default). That's relevant at best for shared applications on the same domain.

Comment: no had feelings, but its horrible approach when the project is huge and more than one developer has to manage the code

Comment: I want to learn more about it if you have any info or ink you could share

Answer (score -1):

The best way to store sensitive users data is sessions.
For example, after validate your login form, you could store `$_SESSION["username"]` or `$_SESSION["userid"]`.

For each PHP script you must to validate similar to this:

```
<?php
session_start();
  if (!isset($_SESSION["username"])) {
 header("location:index.php"); //index.php is the login form
  }
  //your code here
```

If you want to store another user's data for example full name, or any id you should store in session variable too.

What about cookies?
Use cookies for users preferences, for examle: checkbox value, listbox value; but NO sensitive data, finally when logout you should destroy session using:

`// destroy the session 
session_destroy();`

Reference:
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp